# Play 2 Java - validate form using fill and bindFromRequest in update scenario

Tags: java, validation, playframework-2.0, crud

I'm having a hard times figuring out how to do update scenario in Play 2 Java

I have
User.java model

```
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String email;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String fullname;
}
```

And I want to update it, so in my controller I do

```
public Result update(Long id) {
    ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();

    User employee = userService.get(id);

    Form<User> userForm = formFactory.form(User.class).fill(employee);

    // This won't trigger validation because it uses fill() not bind()
    if (userForm.hasError()) {
         result.set("message", userForm.errorsAsJson());

         return badRequest(result);
    }

    // do update here
}
```

Then I try to some different approach like this

```
public Result update(Long id) {
    ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();

    User employee = userService.get(id);

    Form<User> userForm = formFactory.form(User.class).fill(employee);
    userForm = userForm.bindFromRequest();

    // This will trigger validation but bindFromRequest will override my fill(employee) before.
    if (userForm.hasError()) {
         result.set("message", userForm.errorsAsJson());

         return badRequest(result);
    }

    // do update here
}
```

The `bindFromRequest()` above will override my `fill(employee)`. I don't want to do that because when in my request I just want to fill `fullname` and not my `email`, my `email` property will trigger its required validation.

So my question is, how can I only update my `fullname` attribute with the form i fill using existing value and still triggering validation constraints from my model?

Answer (score 0):

Change `userForm = userForm.bindFromRequest();` to `userForm.bindFromRequest();`

I have working code very similar to yours and this is the only difference I've observed.